# Can avoiding nil conjoins be done better?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core

I have a token scanner that simply returns `nil` for characters I'm not interested in. Rather than `conj` the nils to my token vector and then later stripping them all out, I want to simply not add them.

I'm using

```
;; dont conjoin if value false
(defn condj [v val]
  (cond-> v, val (conj val)))
```

to do this. Is there a specific operator or a more concise implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the `cond->` version and often use that to avoid repetition in the `if` version.  Don't forget to be explicit about `false` values, though.  I also like to use Plumatic Schema to be explicit about the data shape entering and leaving the function:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]))

(s/defn condj :- [s/Any]
  "Conjoin an item onto a vector of results if the item is not nil."
  [accum :- [s/Any]
   item :- s/Any]
  (cond-> accum
    (not (nil? item)) (conj item)))

(dotest
  (let [result (-> []
                 (condj :a)
                 (condj :2)
                 (condj false)
                 (condj "four")
                 (condj nil)
                 (condj "last"))]
    ; nil is filtered but false is retained
    (is= result [:a :2 false "four" "last"])))
```

You may also be interested in another version using [my favorite library](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.184/api/tupelo.core#cond-it-%3E):

```
(s/defn condj :- [s/Any]
  "Conjoin an item onto a vector of results if the item is not nil."
  [accum :- [s/Any]
   item :- s/Any]
  (cond-it-> accum
    (not-nil? item) (append it item)))
```

For more complicated forms, using the placeholder symbol `it` makes it explicit where the value is being threaded.  I also like the convenience functions `not-nil?` and `append` since they also make the intent of the code plainer.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can use *transducers* for this. They are explained [here](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers). Our reducing function is `conj` and we construct a transducer `(remove nil?)` that turns this function into one that will ignore `nil`:

```
(def condj ((remove nil?) conj))
```

Note that `remove` is the opposite of `filter`. We can also implement `condj` using `(filter some?)`, [some?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some_q) being a function that is true for any value except `nil`:

```
(def condj ((filter some?) conj))
```

It seems to work:

```
user=> (condj [3 4 5] 9)
[3 4 5 9]
user=> (condj [3 4 5] nil)
[3 4 5]
user=> (condj [3 4 5] false)
[3 4 5 false]
```

Comment: Nice, and the transducer can be simplified further to `(filter some?)` or `(remove nil?)`.

Comment: I was not aware of the `remove` function but it makes perfect sense for such a function to exist. I edited my answer to use `remove` instead of `filter`, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the overly simplified approach is the cleanest here (it's also slightly more concise):

```
(defn condj [v val]
  (if val (conj v val) v))
```

I find that this is much easier to understand quickly. The only downside is `v` is duplicated since it isn't being threaded, but that's not a big loss in such a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `into` instead of `conj`:

```
(into [1 2 3] nil) ;=> [1 2 3]

(into [1 2 3] [4]) ;=> [1 2 3 4]
```

Note: the downside is you must return results in a sequence which adds a bit of overhead. However, if you forget to do this you get an error, it makes it easy to extend the logic when you want to append more than one item, the code is easily understandable and doesn't require any custom functions to be created.